# How to call function after the set state is done (React Hooks)

Tags: react-hooks

How to call function AFTER the `setRest(response)` sets the `rest` to value response.

```
setRest(response)
 callFn(); // <-- how to call this fn synchronously after the setRest?
```

Is it possible using `async` and `await` functions?

Answer (score 0):

With me, I will hook rest and call a function in useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
  callFn()
}, [rest])
```

Comment: any solution without useEffect?